# Specifying only certain source files in CMake

Tags: c++, c, cmake

I am aware of using GLOB to include all source files in CMake but there are certain files I would like to exclude (they may be added in the future after completion/testing) Currently I am using:

```
FILE(READ "io_masterFiles.txt" contents)
STRING(REGEX REPLACE "\n" ";" contents "${contents}")
foreach(io_masterFiles ${contents})
message("${io_masterFiles}")
endforeach()
ADD_LIBRARY(io_master ${contents})
```

with the file ***io_masterfiles.txt*** listing each source file needed

```
AD7991.cpp
ADS7844.cpp
AI633.cpp
AI638.cpp
AI644.cpp
analogFlag.cpp
analogInputBoard.cpp
analogInputDevice.cpp
analogInputList.cpp
analogIoPoint.cpp
boardFactory.cpp
controllerConfig.c
${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/project-specific/MHI-VFD/customIoHandler.cpp (these do not work)
${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/project-specific/MHI-VFD/customIoHandlerFactory.cpp (or this one)
diffVoltage.cpp
digitalFlagBit.cpp
digitalInputList.cpp
digitalIoDevice.cpp
digitalIoPoint.cpp
digitalOutputList.cpp
digitalPort.cpp
DS1731.cpp
EPCOS_B57560G.cpp
gpioChipSelect.cpp
i2cBus.cpp
ioBus.cpp
ioCondition.cpp
ioCondition_Unused.cpp
ioController.cpp
ioMaster.cpp
ioPoint.cpp
L9826.cpp
linear.cpp
loop_4_20.cpp
mcp23S17.cpp
measuredTemperature.cpp
semiKron.cpp
sharedAnalogFlag.cpp
sharedDigitalFlagBit.cpp
spiBus.cpp
voltage.cpp
water.cpp
x11.cpp
x11_01.cpp
```

I was told that is not the preferred way to include files in my project. I have a top level directory and then eight sub-directories and am creating a library with each sub-directory. Could someone please let me know the best way to add these files. I have looked over the documentation but have not been able to come up with anything that works.

Also, one of the sub-directories has dependencies in a different sub-directory so I would need an option that allows pulling source files from different directories.

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: https://github.com/ruslo/sugar/wiki/Collecting-sources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of listing files in a separate .txt, you should list the files off in a CMake variable, say, like so:

```
set( io_master_SRCS
    AD7991.cpp
    ADS7844.cpp
    AI633.cpp
    AI638.cpp
    AI644.cpp
    # and so on
)
add_library( io_master ${io_master_SRCS} )
```

You can then add to this variable in CMakeLists.txt directly when new source files become ready.

Regarding subdirectories, the convention is to have a CMakeLists.txt for each subdirectory that specifies any build targets. You can refer to build targets you've specified elsewhere in the project.

Just as an example, say I had a subfolder called a. Put this in the top-level CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_subdirectory( a )
```

And then in `a/CMakeLists.txt` you could reference the `io_master` library (or any other build target in another subdirectory by name):

```
target_link_libraries( another_target io_master )
```